# iScroll rubberband effect in phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, iscroll

I am working on the below JavaScript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var itemScroll;
        function loadScrollItems() {
            itemScroll = new iScroll('itemWrap',{checkDOMChange:false});
                setTimeout(function () {
                    itemScroll.refresh()
                }, 0);
    }
    var cartScroll;
        function loadScrollCartItems() {
            cartScroll = new iScroll('cartScroller',{checkDOMChange:false});
                setTimeout(function () {
                    cartScroll.refresh()
                }, 0);
    }
</script>
```

With a Kendo UI grid for cartScroller. Now everytime i add a product from itemDiv to the cartGrid (table or kendo ui grid) The scroller acts like a rubber band when scrolled. the ItemDiv is filled with items from ajax so i instantiated a ajaxComplete then loadScrollCartItems still it has the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: If you call refresh() on your iscroll in the console after the page has rendered does it solve your problem?

Comment: i already have a refresh on my code. Also i works now before the setTimeout was set to 100 i changed it to 0 just the what i've posted. Thank you though. :)